# Return new id with DB::insert() in Laravel 4

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

In Laravel 4, when you perform a `DB::insert()`, how can you get the ID of the row that has just been inserted? Similar what we have with the function `->insertGetId()`. Reason for using `DB::insert()` is that its a complex PostgreSQL query that cannot be built using Fluent.

**Example Query:**

```
$newId = DB::insert('insert into users (id, name) values (?, ?)', array(1, 'Dayle'));
echo $newId; // returns 1
```

Answer (score 72):

There is a insertGetId method.

```
$id = DB::table('users')->insertGetId(
    array('id' => 1, 'name' => 'Dayle Rees')
);
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need to pass `RAW` SQL statements to my database, so using Fluent's `insertGetId` won't really help.

Comment: Ahhh sorry I missed that part.

Comment: While this is a way to get an id, it doesn't meet the criteria of the question.

Comment: @Nyxynyx maybe you can solve it by using the above solution and mixing it with using DB::raw statements for values like this `$point_geometry_id =  DB::table('geometries')->insertGetId(array('spatial_geometry' => DB::raw("ST_GeomFromText('$geometryWKT', 4326 )")) ,'id');`

Answer (score 44):

If you take a look at `Illuminate\Database\ConnectionInterface` you can see how these functions are written.  Unfortunately `DB::insert()` returns a boolean from `PDOStatement::execute()` and there is no `DB::insertGetId()` at the moment.  If this would be useful then you should request it on GitHub.

In the mean time, you should be able to use `DB::getPdo()->lastInsertId()`

Comment: Thanks Phil, this is actual answer to the question!

Answer (score 12):

There is a `insertGetId()` method, as follows:

```
$dataset = array('column_id' => 1, 'name' => 'Dayle');
$column_id = DB::table('users')->insertGetId($dataset,'column_id');
```

Answer (score 4):

A bit late with the answer but, I think for psql it's best to use native `RETURNING id`

The query that worked for me was:

```
DB::select(
    DB::raw('insert into threads (created_at, updated_at) values (?, ?) 
    returning id'), [Carbon::now(), Carbon::now()]
);
```

Comment: The ONLY solution I found that could be used for multiple inserts in Laravel 6.x + PgSQL 11.6...

Comment: Was it intentional that the 2 parameters are outside of DB:raw's parenthesis? Shouldn't it be: returning id', [Carbon::now(), Carbon::now()])

Comment: @Jacobski yes, if i’m not mistaken it is the security thing when you use raw sql statement

Answer (score 0):

If you get in complex structure, better to use Eloquent.

Best thing that you need review docs :

http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent

Comment: In querying terms there's little you can do with Eloquent that you can't do with Fluent, it's often just more convenient to do it with Eloquent.

Comment: Of course you can do all. But Class based Database structure  makes  sense and easy to refactoring in future ..

Comment: True, but not really an answer. In my case (and perhaps the OP's) Eloquent would have had to do a lot of db calls, I can accomplish the same in just one SQL query.

Answer (score -3):

After saving the data into the DB you just call `$insertedId = $user->id;` where `$user->save()` is called before the step.

more info [here](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#insert-update-delete)