# Returning primary key from Laravel 5.2 DB on raw query

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

Is there a way to return the primary key in the case of raw query insert?

I have:

```
$sql = "insert into table(field1, field2) select (field1+1), ".$id." from table where field2=".$id." order by field3 desc limit 0,1";
$return = (DB::insert(DB::raw($sql)));
```

My $return is a boolean, so without making a select after this insert, can I get this PK?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15842138/return-new-id-with-dbinsert-in-laravel-4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose there isn't a way to retrieve the PK/last inserted id after the `DB::insert` call.

As you can see in `Illuminate\Database\ConnectionInterface` the `insert` method returns a bool because of returning this from a `PDOstatement::excecute` in `Illuminate\Database\Connection`.

Eventually you use `DB::getPdo()->lastInsertId()` after your `DB::insert`.