# Last inserted id Inside transaction with Lumen/Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, transactions, lumen

How can I get the last inserted id
I use the following code which works:

```html
DB::insert("INSERT INTO members (name,email)values($name,$email)");
$lastID = DB::getPdo() -> lastInsertId();
```

But the following code doesn't give me the last inserted id.

```html
DB::transaction(function () {
    $result = DB::insert("INSERT INTO members (name,email)values($name,$email)");
    $lastID = DB::getPdo() -> lastInsertId();
}, 5);
return $lastID;
```

Even when I use the variable($lastID) outside the transaction it still doesn't work.
What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15842138/return-new-id-with-dbinsert-in-laravel-4  $dataset = array('column_id' => 1, 'name' => 'Dayle');
$column_id = DB::table('users')->insertGetId($dataset,'column_id');

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using the query builder, Laravel has the function [`insertGetId`](https://laravel.com/api/5.6/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_insertGetId) which inserts the row and returns the newly created `id`.

```
$lastid = DB::table('members')->insertGetId(['name' => $name, 'email' => $email]);
```

Comment: Is it possible to use $lastid outside the transaction?

Comment: Sure, once the query returns this value `$lastid` is just a local variable

Answer (score 1):

Please see sample code below. Hope it helps.

```
public function testModel($data) {
    $id = DB::transaction(function() use ($data) {
        $record_id = DB::table('users')->insertGetId($data);

        DB::update('update users set votes = 100 where name = ?', ['John']);

        return $record_id;
    });

    return $id; // this will return the last inserted id which is the $record_id inside the DB::transaction
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get it easily:

```
$last_id = DB::table('members')->insertGetId(['name => $name, 'email => $email]);
```

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me

```
public function testModel($data) {
        $last_id = DB::transaction(function() use ($data) {
            Table::create($data);
            return DB::getPdo()->lastInsertId();
        });
    
        return $last_id; // this will return the last inserted id
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

The trick should be quite simple if you use Model. Let's assume you've `Member` model. So when you try to insert record it returns the inserted record in response.

```
/** Insert record **/
$member = Member::create(['name' => $name, 'email' => $email])

/** your last inserted id will be in $member **/
$lastInsertedId = $member->id
```

Hope this works for you.